# How to plot Imaginary part of a complex function against the Real part of the function (e.g. Cole-Cole Plot)?

Tags: plotting

For a function like Z*(w)=a+(b-a)/(1+iwt) with parameters {a,b,t}, the Im[Z] vs Re[Z] plot appears to be a semi circle with radius (b-a)/2. I have tried ParametricPlot. Looking for a way other than that.

Comment: An example of the function you are considering and what you expect it to look like would be helpful. Please edit your post with more information.

Comment: Did you try with `ParametricPlot` and it didn't work, or are you looking for something else for another reason. How about `ParametricPlot[ReIm[z[0.5 - 2 I, 0, 1, t]], {t, 0, 20}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]`? Or is that not what you're after?

Comment: I have tried it out, but the plot does not show expected nature.